# How to pass a formula as a string?

Tags: r

I'd like to pass a string as the formula in the `aov` function

This is my code

```
      library(fpp)
      
      formula <-
        "score ~ single"
      
      aov(
        formula, 
        credit[c("single", "score")]   
      )
```

My goal is for the output to be the same as this

```
aov(score ~ single,
        credit[c("single", "score")])
```

Comment: `formula <- as.formula("score ~ single")`

Comment: `aov(as.formula( formula )` should also work, I believe (so turning it into a formula inside the `aov()` function).

Comment: Be careful with this.  Formulas have two parts:  the visible part (e.g. `score ~ single`) and the attached environment (where functions like `lm()` will go looking for variables if they aren't in the `data` argument).  Make sure you get both parts right for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question seems very close to [How to pass string formula to R's lm and see the formula in the summary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64487754/how-to-pass-string-formula-to-rs-lm-and-see-the-formula-in-the-summary/64487930#64487930) except that question involves `lm`.

Below, `do.call` ensures that `formula(formula)` is evaluated before being sent to `aov` so that the `Call:` line in the output shows properly; otherwise, it would literally show `formula(formula)`.  `do.call` not only evaluates the formula but would also evaluate `credit` expanding it into a huge output showing all its values rather than the word `credit` so we `quote` it to prevent that.   If you don't care what the `Call:` line looks like it could be shortened to `aov(formula(formula), credit)` .

```
do.call("aov", list(formula(formula), quote(credit)))
```

giving:

```
Call:
   aov(formula = score ~ single, data = credit)

Terms:
                  single Residuals
Sum of Squares    834.84  95658.64
Deg. of Freedom        1       498

Residual standard error: 13.8595
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reformulate` to create the formula on the fly.

```
response <- 'score'
pred <- 'single'
aov(reformulate(pred, response), credit[c("single", "score")])

#Call:
#   aov(formula = score ~ single, data = credit[c("single", "score")])

#Terms:
#                  single Residuals
#Sum of Squares    834.84  95658.64
#Deg. of Freedom        1       498

#Residual standard error: 13.8595
#Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```